# Summary table in SQL/SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to build an SSRS report that looks like this:

```
          2015 2014 2013  
 Company1   Y
 Company2         Y    Y
 Company3         Y
```

To show in which year a company was involved (i.e. had a activity).  I've outputted my sql table to look like this:

```
 CompanyID | CompanyName | Activity | TransactionDate
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm basically trying to take the big table I've made and have SSRS format it properly.

Thanks.

Comment: How familiar with reporting services are you? Have you created reports using it before?

Comment: Yeah pretty familiar. I'm not great at grouping but can figure it out.  I basically took my big table and grouped by company name in SSRS and then to filter I did:
=IIF(CDate(Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value) >= "01/01/2015" AND CDate(Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value) <= "12/31/2015" AND Fields!ACTIVITY.Value="BUSY","YES","")"
for the 2015 column.  This doesn't however work.  I have 3 yes's for 2015, but when I look in the SQL table I have 23 that had an activity in 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a Matrix tablix

1. Use Company Name as your Row Value
2. Use Year(Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value) as your Column value
3. Use Max(iif(Fields!ACTIVITY.Value="BUSY","YES","")) as your Matrix Cell Value

Sort By Company Name and Year(Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value) DESC

Comment: That did not work (mostly due to the way I built the underlying table), but did point me in the correct direction with using MAX, so your comment did allow me to complete the task.  Thank you very much for taking the time.  It's greatly appreciated.